# Python replace within multiline string

Tags: python, string

One of my modules (t_mesg.py) has a multi-line string:

```
tm = """
this
is currently
a
test
message
"""
```

I import this in another module where I would need to replace certain parts of the string with others. However, on the import, the newline chars come in as well and so `tm.replace(...)` would not work.

```
>>> from t_mesg import tm
>>> tm
'\nthis\nis \na\ntest\nmessage\n'
```

If I need to process this imported string to change "is" to "is not" how would I go about it, so that the string looks like this?

```
tm = """
this
is not currently
a
test
message
"""
```

TL;DR - how can I perform the replacement ignoring the newline chars?

Comment: you're witnessing the representation of the string. But it will work ok. Try `print(tm)`

Comment: It's not clear to me, are you asking how to create a multi-line string without newlines? Or how to perform the replacement ignoring the new-lines? or something else?

Comment: `tm.replace('\nis \n', '\nis not\n')` works fine for me. Of course, it doesn't modify `tm`, since strings are immutable. If you want to change `tm`, you need `tm = tm.replace('\nis \n', '\nis not\n')`

Comment: @Chris_Rands - the latter - I need to perform the replacement ignoring the new-lines. I've edited the qn

Comment: @PM2Ring Might not be generic enough. I'd probably replace `\n` with `\s` for the sake of formatting

Comment: probably a regex then

Comment: what do you mean by "ignoring the newline chars"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you want to perform a word replacement in a string. You can do it using regular expressions & word boundaries, and the hell with newlines or not:

```
import re
s = "this\n is \n a good \n question"
s = re.sub(r"\bis\b","is not",s)
print(s)
```

result:

```
this
 is not 
 a good 
 question
```

You can revert back with this (which allows some more newlines to be present between both words and preserves them)

```
s = re.sub(r"\bis\b(\s+)\bnot\b",r"is\1",s)
print(s)
```

prints:

```
this
 is 
 a good 
 question
```

to go a little further, you could introduce punctuation and other non-alpha stuff and using `\W` you could still manage:

```
s = "this\n is - not - \n a good \n question"
s = re.sub(r"\bis(\W+)not\b",r"is\1",s)
print(s)
```

prints ("not" has gone away but not the dash before it):

```
this
 is -  - 
 a good 
 question
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I was trying a regex and it replaced the `is` in `This` as well - I had no idea about the word boundaries. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The replace method doesn’t store the altered value in the same variable. You need to store it in another variable and print it.

```
tm = tm.replace('\nis \n', '\nis not\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try splitting up the string, replacing the word and joining the array back together.

```
tm_array = tm.split("\n")
tm_array[1] = "is not"
new_tm = '\n'.join(tm_array)
```